# Unreliable Compiling of Very Simple Java Program in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation

I'm a few days into learning Java and I am trying to build a simple calculator.

When I run the code in Netbeans, perhaps 30% of the time it works great. The window pops up with my buttons. The other 70% of the time just a blank JFrame pops up.

In both circumstances Netbeans' Output tab is telling me
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: N seconds)

My code is below - I'm certain it contains a untold numbers of problems and errors, but specifically I'm trying to understand why the outcome of executing it is so unreliable.

Thanks in advance,

Ben

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Try1 extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//JFrame
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400,600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Ben's Program");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable ( false );

//JPanel
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(360,100);
    panel.setLocation(20, 20);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

//JPanel 2
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setSize(360,420);
    panel2.setLocation(20, 140);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);

//Button
JButton but1= new JButton("1");
JButton but2= new JButton("2");
JButton but3= new JButton("3");
JButton but4= new JButton("4");
JButton but5= new JButton("5");
JButton but6= new JButton("6");
JButton but7= new JButton("7");
JButton but8= new JButton("8");
JButton but9= new JButton("9");
JButton but0= new JButton("0");
JButton butadd= new JButton("+");
JButton butsub= new JButton("-");
JButton butmulti= new JButton("*"); 
JButton butdiv= new JButton("/");
JButton buteq= new JButton("=");
JButton butclear= new JButton("C");

//Button Layout
    but1.setBounds(10, 81, 89, 23);
    but2.setBounds(126, 81, 89, 23);
    but3.setBounds(225, 81, 89, 23);
    but4.setBounds(10, 115, 89, 23);
    but5.setBounds(126, 115, 89, 23);
    but6.setBounds(225, 115, 89, 23);
    but7.setBounds(10, 149, 89, 23);
    but8.setBounds(126, 149, 89, 23);
    but9.setBounds(225, 149, 89, 23);
    but0.setBounds(126, 183, 89, 23);
    butadd.setBounds(126, 215, 89, 23);
    butsub.setBounds(10, 215, 89, 23);
    butmulti.setBounds(225, 183, 89, 23);
    butdiv.setBounds(225, 149, 89, 23);
    buteq.setBounds(126, 183, 89, 23);
    butclear.setBounds(10, 183, 89, 23);

//Add Panel to Frame
frame.add(panel);
frame.add(panel2);

//Add Buttons to Panel2
panel2.add(but1);
panel2.add(but2);
panel2.add(but3);
panel2.add(but4);
panel2.add(but5);
panel2.add(but6);
panel2.add(but7);
panel2.add(but8);
panel2.add(but9);
panel2.add(butadd);
panel2.add(butsub);
panel2.add(butmulti);
panel2.add(butdiv);
panel2.add(buteq);
panel2.add(butclear);

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the JFrame to be resizable. When it pops up blank, resize it. Did the contents suddenly appear?

If so, you have a refresh issue. Implement the component listener interface, add it with JFrame.addComponentListener, and call JFrame.validate() in the componentShown() handler.

UPDATE:

I tested your code. Move the setVisible call to after the calls to add all the panels and buttons to fix the refresh issue. There are layout issues, use a combination of BorderLayout and GridBagLayout to fix.